# gwan -r dosn't read newest file

Tags: c, linux, scripting, command-line-arguments, g-wan

I've been using Gwan v4.1.18 and for development purposes I often use

```
./gwan -r [somefile]
```

However often I find that when I update the file I am running the updates are found when I execute the above line.

Is this some sort of weird caching being used with -r (I was under the assumption that it was solely used for running scripts and not using the entire Gwan system) or could it be a bug?

No rush, but would love some insight into this behavor

Answer (score 0):

John,

Using G-WAN v4.2.19 (latest version posted a few days ago) I just tried `./gwan -r hello.c` and got:

```
Hello World!
```

Then, I edited `hello.c` to remove the exclamation point and re-running `./gwan -r hello.c` gave:

```
Hello World
```

It seems to work as expected, at least on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit (with GNOME rather than Unity).

That's the `hello.c` file located in the same directory as the `gwan` executable.